# Subjuntivo mal acentuado en Argentina

Tags: subjuntivo

En Argentina es común escuchar el subjuntivo presente mal acentuado para muchos casos. Es muy usado para el imperativo negativo,

> No me toqués!

y también a veces en oraciones como

> Cuando lo hagás, veremos.

Cuál es la explicación de esto? Cómo se llama este uso? De dónde viene? Yo lo uso por tenerlo incorporado de manera nativa, pero intenté buscarlo en todos lados y no encontré nada al respecto.

Answer (score 3):

La acentuación atípica del imperativo (y menos usualmente del subjuntivo) en Argentina se debe al voseo, que en modo indicativo vuelve agudas las formas verbales graves o llanas en 2a persona del singular. Esto se relaciona con la acentuación aguda del "vosotros", que es donde tiene origen el "vos":

- Tú me tocas.
- Vos me tocás. (Cf Vosotros me tocáis)
- Tú lo haces.
- Vos lo hacés. (Cf Vosotros lo hacéis)

En imperativo, el cambio de acentuación es generalizado en afirmativo, no así en negativo ni en subjuntivo, donde muchos rioplatenses usamos el "tú":

- Tocame (en lugar de Tócame) (Cf Tocadme)
- Hacelo (en lugar de Hazlo) (Cf Hacedlo)
- No me toques / No me toqués (ambas formas son válidas en español rioplatense) (Cf No me toquéis)
- No lo hagas / No lo hagás (ídem) (Cf No lo hagáis)

El hablante tiene siempre la tentación de volver agudas las formas verbales en segunda persona del singular, y en algunos casos la concreta y en otros no.

Según [este artículo](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/publicaciones_centros/PDF/brasilia_2012/25_reggi-segre.pdf), el imperativo negativo y el subjuntivo (que comparten la misma forma verbal) oscilan entre el tuteo y el voseo:

> En el caso del Imperativo negativo y del Subjuntivo se suelen utilizar la forma
> voseante y tuteante indiferentemente, aunque en el lenguaje escrito se prefiere la forma tuteante.
>
> Ejemplos:
>
> ¡No te metás! (Cf No os metáis) /¡No te metas!
>
> Quiero que me llamés. (Cf Quiero que me llaméis) /Quiero que me llames.

Debo decir que "Quiero que me llamés" no me suena bien, pero seguramente se trata de usos dialectales que no se pueden aprobar o desaprobar: simplemente existen.

Comment: La falta de tilde en «tocame» es quizás el lugar donde más se ve (aparte de *solo* y *este*, *ese*, etc) el efecto de las reglas ortográficas de 2010.  Respecto a *hagás*, quizás sea por ser irregular.  ¿Decís «no seás» o «no seas», «no caigas» o «no caigás»?

Comment: @user0721090601 Usamos más bien "no seas" y "no caigas".

Comment: Entonces puede estar ahí la razón.  A menos que «no comas» y «no escribas» sean también preferibles frente a «no comás» y «no escribás».

Comment: @user0721090601 Creo que tienes/tenés razón en que el uso o no de la acentuación aguda en el imperativo negativo puede estar en la regularidad o irregularidad del verbo. De todos modos, con "ás" el uso es vacilante en negativo.

Comment: Depende mucho del verbo en sí, pero yo escuché mucho el "no lo hagás"... También igualmente se usa para emplear un tono distinto. Definitivamente siendo rioplatense voy a entender diferente un "no me toques" que un "no me toqués", como si la segunda opción implicara más enojo o impaciencia

Comment: @IakaNoe Tenés razón. Voy a modificar la respuesta.

Comment: Entonces en resumen, es solo un error por costumbre en el que tratamos de hacer sonar "más imperativo" al subjuntivo usado como imperativo; ya que en el imperativo común se usa la acentuación aguda por voceo?

Comment: @IakaNoe No diría que es un error, sino un uso que se enmarca dentro del sistema del voseo.

Comment: @Gustavson pero no es correcto... O si? Hay alguna fuente oficial que describa esto?

Comment: @IakaNoe ¿Te referís al imperativo afirmativo, al imperativo negativo y subjuntivo, o a ambos?

Comment: @Gustavson al hecho de darle acentuación aguda al subjuntivo usado como imperativo

Comment: @IakaNoe Estoy agregando una referencia valiosa que encontré.